# Вот такой вот квест по языку Си

Tags: c

Создать программу src/char_decode.c, которая принимает в качестве
параметра командной строки режим работы (0 — кодирование или 1 — декодирование).
Если выбран режим декодирования, то программа должна принимать из stdin разделенные
пробелом двухсимвольные строки и выдавать в stdout декодированные символы, разделенные
также пробелом. При кодировании выполняется обратная операция. Подзадачи кодирования и
декодирования должны быть выделены в отдельные функции. Обратить внимание на ASCII таблицу.
В случае ошибки выводить "n/a". Признаком окончания ввода служит символ переноса строки.
Массивы использовать нельзя:(

Параметры командной строки: 0
Входные данные: W O R L D
Выходные данные: 57 4F 52 4C 44

Параметры командной строки: 0
Входные данные: WORLD
Выходные данные: n/a

Параметры командной строки: 1
Входные данные: 48 45 4C 4C 4F
Выходные данные: H E L L O

Параметры командной строки: 1
Входные данные: 48454C4C4F
Выходные данные: n/a

По отдельности слово W O R L D работает а вместе когда написано не знаю как обработать, ни и цифры тоже. Вроде близко хожу, но не попадаю.

```
''' #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int hextochar(){

int i=0;  

scanf("%x", &i);

printf("%c\n", i);
while(i!='\n'){
    scanf("%x", &i);    
    
    printf("%c\n", i);  
}
return (0);

}

int chartohex(){
char ch;
scanf("%c", &ch);

printf("%x ", ch);

while(ch!='\n'){
    scanf("%c", &ch); 
    if (ch==' ')
        continue;
    if (ch=='\n')
        return (0);
    printf("%x ", ch);  
}
return (0);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

if (argc<2 || argc>2)
    printf("n/a");  
char d=*argv[1];     

if (d=='1'){
 hextochar();
}
if (d=='0'){
chartohex();
}
}'''
```

Comment: Читайте stdin по одному символу (getchar()-ом) в `chartohex()` и проверяйте на пробел. А в `hextochar()` так же посимвольно, но сначала читаете 2 раза, проверяете, что это 16-ричные цифры, потом читаете следующий символ и проверяете, что это пробел. Это будет правильная стратегия, поскольку, читая данные scanf-ом вы не сможете контролировать число пробелов (или ведущих нулей в формате `%x`)

Comment: Можно попросить код? Не совсем понимаю как реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, функция `hextochar()` (которая в вашем коде почти ничего не делает) может выглядеть, например, так:

```
// Check is `c`  hex digit
// and returns hex value in low 4 bits + set bit 7 if hexdigit or 0 if not
static int
is_hex (int c)
{
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') 
    return (c - '0') | 0x80;
  
  c |= 0x20; // upper case to lower
  return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') ?  ((c - 'a') + 10) | 0x80 : 0;
}

static int
n_a (int c)
{
  puts("n/a");
  return c;
}


/*
  Read one line in format "XX XX XX ... XX XX\n"
  and print it in ASCII
  
  Returns any not 0 and print "n/a" if format mismatch
  Returns EOF (and print "n/a" if EOF in the middle of line)
  Returns 0 if line format is valid
*/
int
hextochar ()
{
  int c1, c2, xd1, xd2;
  int nc = 0;
  
  while ((c1 = getchar()) != EOF) {
    nc++;
    if (c1 == '\n')
      return n_a(c1); // return '\n';  // any error in the  line
    if ((c2 = getchar()) == EOF || c2 == '\n')
      return n_a(c2); // return '\n' or EOF;  // any error in the middle of line
    if (!(xd1 = is_hex(c1)) || !(xd2 = is_hex(c2)))
      return n_a(1); // return any error (not 0, and not '\n') in the middle of line
    xd1 &= 0xf;
    xd2 &= 0xf;
    printf("%c", (xd1 << 4) | xd2);
    c1 = getchar();
    if (c1 == ' ' || c1 == '\n') { // print '\n' as part of line format too
      printf("%c", c1);
      if (c1 == '\n')
        return 0; // OK, all data in the line decoded
    } else
      return n_a(c1 | 0x1); // return not 0 or EOF;  // any error in the middle of line
  }

  if (nc)
    puts("n/a");
  return EOF; // EOF in the beginning of line may be error too, then caller puts("n\a");
}

int
skipline (FILE *in)
{
  int c;

  while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
    if (c == '\n')
      break;

  return c;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac != 2)
  Errexit:
    exit((printf("Usage: %s 1 | 0\n", av[0]), 1));

  int c = av[1][0];
  if (av[1][1] || !(c == '1' || c == '0'))
    goto Errexit;

  if (c == '1') {
    while ((c = hextochar()) != EOF)
      if (c && c != '\n') 
        if (skipline(stdin) == EOF)
          break;
  } else {
    puts("Not implemented yet");
  }
  
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```